# Triple buffering without buffers?

Tags: metal

[Metal Best Practices Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/MTLBestPracticesGuide/BufferBindings.html) states that

> The setVertexBytes:length:atIndex: method is the best option for binding a very small amount (less than 4 KB) of dynamic buffer data to a vertex function

I believe this means that instead storing uniforms in an overly complicated manually memory managed dynamic buffer, it's best to simply update model/view/projection matrices without using any buffer at all, by using `setVertexBytes` and `setFragmentBytes`.

My question is, that in this case, as there is no dynamic buffer at all (only static vertex data), what are we calling triple buffering?

Is it simply because we have a semaphore with `value: 3` left now?

Comment: I suspect that this is where "a very small amount" comes in, you'd still want triple buffering for larger data.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Presumably your render targets are still double or triple buffered, regardless of how you manage uniform data...?

Comment: This might be a particularity of Metal, I'm not sure. But I think in case of Metal you just manually manage your render targets, with a semaphore. I'm just guessing, but if I remove the semaphore it behaves like double-buffering (GPU displays one frame while CPU is encoding the next).